How make own d3.arc function?
I try make own d3.arc function but can't count arc's large-arc-flag and sweep-flag.
createArc (bands) {
    const innerRadius = this.maxRadius * 0.8
    const outerRadius = this.maxRadius * 0.95
    const startAngle = this.scaleLinear(bands[0])
    const endAngle = this.scaleLinear(bands[1])
    const MX = Math.cos(startAngle) * outerRadius
    const MY = -Math.sin(startAngle) * outerRadius
    const A1X = Math.cos(endAngle) * outerRadius
    const A1Y = -Math.sin(endAngle) * outerRadius
    const LX = Math.cos(endAngle) * innerRadius
    const LY = -Math.sin(endAngle) * innerRadius
    const A2X = Math.cos(startAngle) * innerRadius
    const A2Y = -Math.sin(startAngle) * innerRadius
    return `M${MX},${MY}A${outerRadius},${outerRadius},0,0,1,${A1X},${A1Y}L${LX},${LY}A${innerRadius},${innerRadius},0,0,0,${A2X},${A2Y}Z`
}

Example of bands parameter([100, 110])
I get coords and radiuses for arc but can't understand how to count arc's large-arc-flag and sweep-flag. (0,1 and 0,0 in example above)
